# How to setup path to jupyter lab of activated environment

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I need to configure several pieces of software to access various executables that might change with conda environments.

I know that this is broad so lets stick to jupyter lab, I want to add an item to Windows' context menu. I have all of keys in my registy setup except for `Default` of `command` and this entry needs to path to jupyter lab.

As I understand all anaconda's executables will be found in

> Users\my.name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

This is the part where I'm lost directory above contains "Scripts" and "env" after examining each it looks to me like "Scripts" contains executables for base(root) environment and env contains files specific to each environment.

Is there another directory that I missed, that contains files/links to currently activated environment?

Maybe my approach is to0 direct so is there a programmatic way to  figure out where is the executable I'm looking for?

I should point out that I'm working on Win 10 machine.